# Moment Generating function of one random variable among multiple random variables

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

If the moment generating function of $X_1, X_2, X_3$ is

[image]

How to find the moment generating function of just X1?

Need some guidance on how to start..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$M_{(X,Y,Z)}(u,0,0)=E\left[\mathrm e^{u\cdot X+0\cdot Y+0\cdot Z}\right]=E\left[\mathrm e^{u\cdot X}\right]=M_{X}(u)$$

Comment: I know moment generating function of $X_1$ is E($e^ux$). but how to find the value of that.

Comment: They *gave* you the value.  Look at the far-left and far-right of that equation, and then substitute the values from the far-left into your first equation, to get an algebraic expression for Mx(u).

Comment: @cloudfeet dun understand, can show it to me?

Comment: Put $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(u,0,0)$ in the formula you have been given.

Comment: so moment generating function for $X_1$ is $e^(1/2u^2)$? am i right?

Comment: @Did am i right?

Comment: I fail to get it. Are you unable to plug $u_1=u$ and $u_2=u_3=0$ into the formula for $M_X(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ you put an image of in your question? Yes the result is $e^{u^2/2}$.